# Proper way to solve $2\tan^{-1}(\cos x)=\tan^{-1}(2\csc x)$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

Solve

> $$
> 2\tan^{-1}(\cos x)=\tan^{-1}(2\csc x)
> $$

If $|\cos x|<1\implies x>0$,
$$
\text{L.H.S}=\tan^{-1}\frac{2\cos x}{1-\cos^2x}=\tan^{-1}\frac{2\cos x}{\sin^2x}=\tan^{-1}\frac{2}{\sin x}\\
\implies {\sin x.\tan x}=\sin x\implies x=0 \text{ or }\frac{\pi}{4}\\
\boxed{x=\frac{\pi}{4}}\text{ as $x>0$} 
$$
If $|\cos x|>1\implies x<0$,
$$
\text{L.H.S}=\pi+\tan^{-1}\frac{2\cos x}{1-\cos^2x}=\pi+\tan^{-1}\frac{2\cos x}{\sin^2x}=\tan^{-1}\frac{2}{\sin x}\\
$$

How do I prove second case does not hold in this problem ?

Comment: When $|\cos x| > 1$ ?

Comment: General solution will be $\{n\pi , n\pi + \frac{\pi}{4}\}, n \in \Bbb Z$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $2\tan^{-1}(\cos x)=\tan^{-1}(2\csc x),$

$$-\dfrac\pi2<2\tan^{-1}(\cos x)<\dfrac\pi2$$

$$\iff-\tan\dfrac\pi4<\cos x<\tan\dfrac\pi4$$

as $\arctan y$ is an increasing function in real $y$

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what benefit the division into cases can give.

Take the tangent of both sides; then, using the duplication formula for the tangent, you get
$$
\frac{2\cos x}{1-\cos^2x}=\frac{2}{\sin x}
$$
This simplifies to
$$
\sin^2x=\sin x\cos x
$$
This is $\sin x(\sin x-\cos x)=0$.

Since $\sin x\ne0$ (because of the cosecant in the statement), you remain with
$$
\sin x-\cos x=0
$$